# CUDA device function pointers in structure without static pointers or symbol copies

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

My intended program flow would look like the following if it were possible:

```
typedef struct structure_t
{
  [...]
  /* device function pointer. */
  __device__ float (*function_pointer)(float, float, float[]);
  [...]
} structure;

[...]

/* function to be assigned. */
__device__ float
my_function (float a, float b, float c[])
{
  /* do some stuff on the device. */
  [...]
}

void
some_structure_initialization_function (structure *st)
{
  /* assign. */
  st->function_pointer = my_function;
  [...]
}
```

This is not possible, and ends in a familiar error during compilation regarding the placement of __device__ in the structure.

```
 error: attribute "device" does not apply here
```

There are some examples of similar types of problems here on stackoverflow, but they all involve the use of static pointers outside the structure. Examples are [device function pointers as struct members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102945/device-function-pointers-as-struct-members) and [device function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000388/device-function-pointers). I've taken a similar approach with success previously in other codes where it's easy for me to use static device pointers and define them outside of any structures. Currently though this is a problem. It's written as an API of sorts and the user may define one or two or dozens of structures which need to include a device function pointer. So, defining static device pointers outside of the structure is a major problem.

I'm fairly certain the answer exists within the posts I have linked above, through use symbol copies, but I've not been able to put them to successful use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do *is* possible, but you have made a few mistakes in the way you are declaring and defining the structures that will hold and use the function pointer.

> This is not possible, and ends in a familiar error during compilation
>   regarding the placement of __device__ in the structure.
>
> ```
>  error: attribute "device" does not apply here
> ```

This is only because you are attempting to assign a memory space to a structure or class data member, which is illegal in CUDA. The memory space of the all class or structure data members are implicitly set when you define or instantiate a class. So something only slighlty different (and more concrete):

```
typedef float (* fp)(float, float, float4);

struct functor
{
    float c0, c1;
    fp f;

    __device__ __host__
    functor(float _c0, float _c1, fp _f) : c0(_c0), c1(_c1), f(_f) {};

    __device__ __host__
    float operator()(float4 x) { return f(c0, c1, x); };
};

__global__
void kernel(float c0, float c1, fp f, const float4 * x, float * y, int N)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    struct functor op(c0, c1, f);
    for(int i = tid; i < N; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
        y[i] = op(x[i]);
    }
}
```

is perfectly valid. The function pointer `fp` in `functor` is implicitly a `__device__` function when an instance of `functor` is instantiated in device code. If it were instantiated in host code, the function pointer would implicitly be a host function. In the kernel, a device function pointer passed as argument is used to instantiate a `functor` instance. All perfectly legal.

I believe I am correct in saying that there is no direct way to get the address of a `__device__` function in host code, so you still require some static declarations and symbol manipulation. This *might* be different in CUDA 5, but I have not tested it to see. If we flesh out the device code above with a couple of `__device__` functions and some supporting host code:

```
__device__ __host__ 
float f1 (float a, float b, float4 c)
{
    return a + (b * c.x) +  (b * c.y) + (b * c.z) + (b * c.w);
}

__device__ __host__
float f2 (float a, float b, float4 c)
{
    return a + b + c.x + c.y + c.z + c.w;
}

__constant__ fp function_table[] = {f1, f2};

int main(void)
{
    const float c1 = 1.0f, c2 = 2.0f;
    const int n = 20;
    float4 vin[n];
    float vout1[n], vout2[n];
    for(int i=0, j=0; i<n; i++) {
        vin[i].x = j++; vin[i].y = j++;
        vin[i].z = j++; vin[i].w = j++;
    }

    float4 * _vin;
    float * _vout1, * _vout2;
    size_t sz4 = sizeof(float4) * size_t(n);
    size_t sz1 = sizeof(float) * size_t(n);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&_vin, sz4);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&_vout1, sz1);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&_vout2, sz1);
    cudaMemcpy(_vin, &vin[0], sz4, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    fp funcs[2];
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&funcs, "function_table", 2 * sizeof(fp));

    kernel<<<1,32>>>(c1, c2, funcs[0], _vin, _vout1, n);
    cudaMemcpy(&vout1[0], _vout1, sz1, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 

    kernel<<<1,32>>>(c1, c2, funcs[1], _vin, _vout2, n);
    cudaMemcpy(&vout2[0], _vout2, sz1, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 

    struct functor func1(c1, c2, f1), func2(c1, c2, f2); 
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%2d %6.f %6.f (%6.f,%6.f,%6.f,%6.f ) %6.f %6.f %6.f %6.f\n", 
                i, c1, c2, vin[i].x, vin[i].y, vin[i].z, vin[i].w,
                vout1[i], func1(vin[i]), vout2[i], func2(vin[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you get a fully compilable and runnable example. Here two `__device__` functions and a static function table provide a mechanism for the host code to retrieve `__device__` function pointers at runtime. The kernel is called once with each `__device__` function and the results displayed, along with the exact same functor and functions instantiated and called from *host* code (and thus running on the host) for comparison:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -Xptxas="-v" -o function_pointer function_pointer.cu 

ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelffPFfff6float4EPKS_Pfi' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelffPFfff6float4EPKS_Pfi
    16 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z2f1ff6float4
    24 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z2f2ff6float4
    24 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 16 registers, 356 bytes cmem[0], 16 bytes cmem[3]

$ ./function_pointer 
 0      1      2 (     0,     1,     2,     3 )     13     13      9      9
 1      1      2 (     4,     5,     6,     7 )     45     45     25     25
 2      1      2 (     8,     9,    10,    11 )     77     77     41     41
 3      1      2 (    12,    13,    14,    15 )    109    109     57     57
 4      1      2 (    16,    17,    18,    19 )    141    141     73     73
 5      1      2 (    20,    21,    22,    23 )    173    173     89     89
 6      1      2 (    24,    25,    26,    27 )    205    205    105    105
 7      1      2 (    28,    29,    30,    31 )    237    237    121    121
 8      1      2 (    32,    33,    34,    35 )    269    269    137    137
 9      1      2 (    36,    37,    38,    39 )    301    301    153    153
10      1      2 (    40,    41,    42,    43 )    333    333    169    169
11      1      2 (    44,    45,    46,    47 )    365    365    185    185
12      1      2 (    48,    49,    50,    51 )    397    397    201    201
13      1      2 (    52,    53,    54,    55 )    429    429    217    217
14      1      2 (    56,    57,    58,    59 )    461    461    233    233
15      1      2 (    60,    61,    62,    63 )    493    493    249    249
16      1      2 (    64,    65,    66,    67 )    525    525    265    265
17      1      2 (    68,    69,    70,    71 )    557    557    281    281
18      1      2 (    72,    73,    74,    75 )    589    589    297    297
19      1      2 (    76,    77,    78,    79 )    621    621    313    313
```

If I have understood your question correctly, the above example should give you pretty much all the design patterns you need to implement your ideas in device code.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed reply. This gave me everything I needed to implement my ideas in my code. Already up and running. I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Why did you remove the C tag?

Comment: Because this is really a C++ question. Despite being labelled as "CUDA C", the device language is really a subset of C++. Both host and device code are compiled with a C++ compiler and the semantics of structures, pointers and functions follow C++ conventions.

Comment: well that's fine but my code is completely in C and there's nothing from C++ in my question really. if anything it should have both i guess.

Comment: @coastal: The rationale is pretty straight forward. You look at those structures in your question and see "plain C". The toolchain you use to compile it is C++ and sees C++ structures containing only data members. The reason for the syntax error you complained about is because C++ semantics apply to those data members. When you write code and compile with the CUDA toolchain, you are writing C++ code, whether you realise it or not.

Comment: that logic really just doesn't do it for me. i'm not saying anything you said was incorrect ... of course it's correct. but *i* am not writing C++ code, and if i were, there's a good chance i'd structure my example differently in the initial question. if i don't have to "realize" i am writing c++ code, and someone goes searching for this question, shouldn't c also be a tag? am i writing in fortran because i use the fortran interface to lapack in my c code?

Comment: the real question is very simple. is this relevant to a C audience? the answer is clearly yes.