# CUDA: Copy dynamically created array of function pointers on the CPU to GPU memory

Tags: cuda, function-pointers

I would like to create a list of function pointers dynamically on the CPU (with some sort of `push_back()` method called from `main()`) and copy it to a GPU `__constant__` or `__device__` array, without needing to resort to static `__device__` function pointers. I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857045/cuda-device-function-pointers-in-structure-without-static-pointers-or-symbol-cop) is related to my problem; however, my goal is to create the `__host__` function pointer array iteratively and then copy it to the `__constant__` function pointer array instead of initialising the latter on declaration.

A working code example with static function pointers (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000388/device-function-pointers) or [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/457094/cuda-programming-and-performance/how-can-i-use-__device__-function-pointer-in-cuda-/3/)) would be:

common.h:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#define num_functions 3

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),     file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

// fptr_t: Pointer to void function that takes two integer lvalues
typedef void (*fptr_t)(int&, int&);

// some examples of void(int&, int&) functions...
__device__ void Add(int &a, int &b) {printf("Add... %i + %i = %i\n", a, b, a+b);}
__device__ void Subtract(int &a, int &b) {printf("Subtract... %i - %i = %i\n", a, b, a-b);}
__device__ void Multiply(int &a, int &b) {printf("Multiply... %i * %i = %i\n", a, b, a*b);}

// List of function pointers in device memory
__constant__ fptr_t constant_fList[num_functions];

// Kernel called from main(): choose the function to apply whose index is equal to thread ID
__global__ void kernel(int a, int b) {
  fptr_t f;
  if (threadIdx.x < num_functions) {
    f = constant_fList[threadIdx.x];
    f(a,b);
  }
}

#endif
```

main.cu:

```
#include "common.h"

// Static device function pointers
__device__ fptr_t p_Add = Add;
__device__ fptr_t p_Sub = Subtract;
__device__ fptr_t p_Mul = Multiply;

// Load function list to constant memory
void loadList_staticpointers() {
  fptr_t h_fList[num_functions];
  gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_fList[0], p_Add, sizeof(fptr_t)) );
  gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_fList[1], p_Sub, sizeof(fptr_t)) );
  gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_fList[2], p_Mul, sizeof(fptr_t)) );
  gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constant_fList, h_fList, num_functions * sizeof(fptr_t)) );
}

int main() {

  loadList_staticpointers();
  int a = 12, b = 15;
  kernel<<<1,3>>>(a, b);
  gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

  return 0;
}
```

Specs: GeForce GTX 670, compiled for `-arch=sm_30`, CUDA 6.5, Ubuntu 14.04

I wish to avoid the use of static device function pointers, as appending each function would require code maintenance on the user side - declaration of a new static pointer like `p_Add` or `p_Mul`, manipulation of `void loadList_functionpointers()`, etc. To make it clear, I am trying something like the following (crashing) code:

main_wrong.cu:

```
#include "common.h"
#include <vector>

// Global variable: list of function pointers in host memory
std::vector<fptr_t> vec_fList;

// Add function to functions list
void addFunc(fptr_t f) {vec_fList.push_back(f);}

// Upload the functions in the std::vector<fptr_t> to GPU memory
// Copies CPU-side pointers to constant_fList, therefore crashes on kernel call 
void UploadVector() {
  fptr_t* h_vpointer = vec_fList.data();
  gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constant_fList, h_vpointer, vec_fList.size() * sizeof(fptr_t)) );
}

int main() {

  addFunc(Add);
  addFunc(Subtract);
  addFunc(Multiply);
  int a = 12, b = 15;

  UploadVector();

  kernel<<<1,3>>>(a, b); // Wrong to call a host-side function pointer from a kernel
  gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

  return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that function pointers *pointing to host addresses* are copied to the GPU and are unusable by the kernel, which needs *pointers pointing to GPU addresses* when the function `f(a,b)` is called. Populating a host-side array with device-side pointers would work for me with raw data (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931630/copying-array-of-pointers-into-device-memory-and-back-cuda)) but not with function pointers. Trivial attempts with Unified Memory have failed as well... so far, I have only found static device-side pointers to work. Is there no other way to copy a dynamically created CPU array of function pointers onto the GPU?

Comment: as a side note: why do need to use function pointers at all? Which problem are you trying to solve with them?

Comment: I am developing a code used for particle simulation. Particles interact with each other in different ways according to each other's properties, so the function applied to each interaction has to be determined on the fly.

Comment: how is this better than using a `switch` inside the kernel?

Comment: A `switch` inside the kernel involves manipulation of the code on the user side - each time they introduce a new function (that they already need to code), a new case has to be introduced for the `switch`. I do not want the user to need to understand CUDA mechanics but provide them with some `addFunc(f)` mechanism to be called from `main()`, the only C++ code would involve `f`.

Comment: I see; Is it feasible that users recompile the entire code when adding new functions? then you could use some template logic to generate that switch for you automatically. I also guess this gives the compiler more chances to optimize the code. If using a template is a possibility for you, can you upgrade to CUDA 7 to enable the use of C++11?

Comment: Yes, in principle compiling the entire code is sub-optimal but not a problem. About the template idea, do you mean something like `kernel<Add><<<1,3>>>(a,b)` using each function as a template parameter? I am not sure if I understood your suggestion but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use C++11 (supported since CUDA 7), you could use the following to auto-generate the function table:

```
template <fptr_t... Functions>
__global__ void kernel(int a, int b)
{
  constexpr auto num_f = sizeof...(Functions);

  constexpr fptr_t table[] = { Functions... };

  if (threadIdx.x < num_f)
  {
    fptr_t f = table[threadIdx.x];
    f(a,b);
  }
}
```

You would then call this kernel using

```
kernel<Add, Subtract, Multiply><<<1,3>>>(a, b);
```

Comment: Strictly, templates have nothing to do with function pointers, as classes get generates at compile time..

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by **m.s.**'s answer, I chose to *pass the function pointer as a template parameter* -this was in fact the key to solve my problem- and discovered that filling a `__device__` array of function pointers `dev_fList` from the `main()` function iteratively without the help of static function pointers *is* indeed possible, plus C++11 compatibility is not even needed!

Here is a working example on a `__device__` array in global memory. I have not tried its constant memory counterpart yet, but once a global memory array has been satisfactorily created, my guess is that a `cudaMemcpyToSymbol(..., cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice)` should do the trick.

A kernel `kernel()` creates a GPU address for function pointer `dev_f` and copies the function `f` that was passed as a template argument. Since this is an iterative process from the CPU, only one thread (thread `0`) is involved in this kernel, which is launched with configuration `<<<1,1>>>`. The static variable `count_f` takes care of indexing in `dev_fList`.

common.h:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#define num_functions 3

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

// fptr_t: Pointer to void function that takes two integer lvalues
typedef void (*fptr_t)(int&, int&);

// some examples of void(int&, int&) functions...
__device__ void Add(int &a, int &b) {printf("Add... %i + %i = %i\n", a, b, a+b);}
__device__ void Subtract(int &a, int &b) {printf("Subtract... %i - %i = %i\n", a, b, a-b);}
__device__ void Multiply(int &a, int &b) {printf("Multiply... %i * %i = %i\n", a, b, a*b);}

// List of function pointers in device memory
// Note that, in my example, it resides in global memory space, not constant memory
__device__ fptr_t dev_fList[num_functions];

#endif
```

main.cu:

```
#include "common.h"

// Index in dev_fList[] == number of times addFunc<>() was launched
static int count_f = 0;

// Kernel that copies function f to the GPU
template<fptr_t f>
__global__ void kernel(int a, int b, int idx) {
  fptr_t dev_f = f; // Create device function pointer
  dev_fList[idx] = dev_f; // Populate the GPU array of function pointers
  dev_fList[idx](a,b); // Make sure that the array was populated correctly
}

// Add function to functions list
template<fptr_t f>
void addFunc(const int &a, const int &b) {
  if (count_f >= num_functions) {
    std::cout << "Error: not enough memory statically allocated on device!\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  kernel<f><<<1,1>>>(a,b,count_f);
  gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
  count_f++;
}

int main() {
  int a = 12, b = 15;
  addFunc<Add>(a,b);
  addFunc<Subtract>(a,b);
  addFunc<Multiply>(a,b);

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit: Added copy of the array of function pointers to constant memory**

For what it's worth, here is how to copy our `dev_fList` array to constant memory:

In common.h:

```
__constant__ fptr_t cst_fList[num_functions];

__global__ void cst_test(int a, int b, int idx) {
   if (threadIdx.x < idx) cst_fList[threadIdx.x](a,b);
}
```

In main.cu `main()` function, after all desired functions have been added:

```
  fptr_t *temp;
  gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpyFromSymbol((void**)&temp, dev_fList[0], count_f * sizeof(fptr_t)) );
  gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cst_fList[0], &temp, count_f * sizeof(fptr_t)) );

  cst_test<<<1,count_f>>>(a,b, count_f);
  gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

It may look ugly as I understand that memory is transferred to the host via `temp` and then back to the device; more elegant suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score -2):

It is impossible to use dynamically created CUDA device function pointers (at least not without crash or UB). The template based solutions work at compile time (not dynamic). The CUDA device function pointer approaches you see everywhere need device symbols in global space. This means that for every function a device function pointer must be already declared. This also means you cannot use normal C function pointers as reference, which are e.g. set at runtime. In comprehension, using CUDA device function pointers is questionable. Template based approaches look user-friendly, but are per definition not dynamic.

Example showing structure with function pointers:

This example shows a structure having some function pointers. In normal C++ code, you can set and change the device function pointers while the program is running (dynamically). With CUDA this example below is *impossible*, because the function pointers in the struct are no valid device symbols. This means they cannot be used with "cudaMemcpyFromSymbol". To circumvent this, either the original function (target of the function pointers) or global cuda device function pointers must be created. Both is not dynamic.

This is dynamic assignment:

```
typedef float (*pDistanceFu) (float, float);
typedef float (*pDecayFu)    (float, float, float);

// In C++ you can set and reset the function pointer during run time whenever you want ..
struct DistFunction {
  /*__host__ __device__*/ pDistanceFu distance; // uncomment for NVCC ..
  /*__host__ __device__*/ pDecayFu rad_decay;
  /*__host__ __device__*/ pDecayFu lrate_decay;
};

// you can do what you want ..
DistFunction foo, bar;
foo.distance = bar.distance;
// ..
```

This is how it should be with CUDA, but it will fail, because there is no valid device symbol :(

```
pDistanceFu hDistance; 
pDecayFu hRadDay; 
pDecayFu hLRateDecay; 

void DeviceAssign(DistFunction &dist) {      
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&hDistance, dist.distance, sizeof(pDistanceFu) );
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&hRadDay, dist.rad_decay, sizeof(pDecayFu) );
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&hLRateDecay, dist.lrate_decay, sizeof(pDecayFu) );

  dist.distance = hDistance;
  dist.rad_decay = hRadDay;
  dist.lrate_decay = hLRateDecay;
}
```

Here is the classical way, but you notice, it is not dynamic anymore because the device symbol must refer to the function reference not a pointer which may chnage during run-time..

```
// .. and this would work
#ifdef __CUDACC__
  __host__ __device__
#endif
inline float fcn_rad_decay (float sigma0, float T, float lambda) {
  return std::floor(sigma0*exp(-T/lambda) + 0.5f);
}

__device__ pDistanceFu pFoo= fcn_rad_decay; // pointer must target a reference, no host pointer possible 

void DeviceAssign2(DistFunction &dist) {      
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&hLRateDecay, &fcn_rad_decay, sizeof(pDecayFu) );
  // the same:
  // cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&hLRateDecay, pFoo, sizeof(pDecayFu) );
  // ..

  dist.lrate_decay = hLRateDecay;
  // ..
}
```

Comment: Apparently I am quite dense.  Apologies.  You've made some claims about  CUDA device function pointers that I want to be clear about.  I suspect you are restating something that has been declared elsewhere (and is [documented]()) - you can't directly take the address of a device function in host code.  1. Do you feel that is equivalent to your claims?  If not, can you give a *short* example of a "dynamic" device pointer usage in ordinary (host/CPU) code?

Comment: 2. Presumably, anything you can do on the host, I can do *on the device* in CUDA.  So your claims revolve around (I think) the use of device function pointers *dispatched from host code*.  Is that correct?  Because I think I should be able to get device function pointers workable in device code, comparable to any host example in host code you would produce?

Comment: sorry, [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-pointers) is the documentation link I meant to include in my first comment above

Comment: It is impossible to set a device function pointer to a host function pointer. You can down-vote as much as you want, the code is static :D

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer.  If you like, I can prove it :D   And you are certainly correct that it is impossible to set a device function pointer to a host function pointer (and make any sensible use of it, anyway).

Comment: Then I wonder what's the problem with this answer. Templates are per definition not dynamic and the CUDA SDK solution is neither.